# MWPhotoBrowser on IOS 10 not showing top bar with back button

Tags: ios, mwphotobrowser

I'm using this library to show pictures/videos from a custom location folder on my ios device https://github.com/mwaterfall/MWPhotoBrowser. It manage to show the picture and the video, BUT, it's now showing the back button neither the topbar on my iphone, I'm invoking the library from my react native plugin.

```
MWPhotoBrowser *browser = [[MWPhotoBrowser alloc] initWithDelegate:self];

  browser.displayActionButton = YES; // Show action button to allow sharing, copying, etc (defaults to YES)
 browser.displayNavArrows = NO; // Whether to display left and right nav arrows on toolbar (defaults to NO)
 browser.displaySelectionButtons = NO; // Whether selection buttons are shown on each image (defaults to NO)
 browser.zoomPhotosToFill = YES; // Images that almost fill the screen will be initially zoomed to fill (defaults to YES)
 browser.alwaysShowControls = NO; // Allows to control whether the bars and controls are always visible or whether they fade away to show the
 [browser setCurrentPhotoIndex:index];

 // Manipulate
 [browser showNextPhotoAnimated:YES];
 [browser showPreviousPhotoAnimated:YES];
 [browser.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, browser.view.frame.size.width,       browser.view.frame.size.height)];
 AppDelegate *delegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
 [delegate.window addSubview:browser.view];
 [delegate.navigationController pushViewController:browser animated:YES  ];
```

It shows the picture and video without any problem, but it's not showing the back button. Any ideas?

Comment: same here. for me, after i present, it doesn't show navigation bar.